# update: function edit with other design

Tags: oracle, function, oracle11g

I change the design for the program but don't know why cannot to show any record. The function design to get the function "bus code" and "bus dir name" and receive the parameter to the function use.

```
   FUNCTION get_abc_text(iv_name varchar2,
                     iv_bus varchar2,
                     iv_bus_name VARCHAR2)

  RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
     v_abc varchar2(500); 
 v_return varchar2(500);  

 BEGIN


   v_abc :=  'SELECT bus_number2' || iv_bus_name || '
               FROM city_bus_value_vl fbus,
                    city_bus_value_sets fbusa,

                 (SELECT fbus.bus_value bus_group, fbus.bus_value2,
                         fbus.bus_description bus_desc

                       FROM city_bus_value_vl fbus,
                            city_bus_value_sets fbusa

                        WHERE fbus.bus_value_id = fbusa.bus_value_id
                          AND fbus.bus_value_name = ''BUS_GP''

                          ) bus_gp,




                  (SELECT fbus.bus_number1 bus_code,
                          fbus.bus_value bus_no
                         FROM city_bus_value_vl fbus,
                              city_bus_value_sets fbusa,

                         WHERE fbus.bus_value_id = fbusa.bus_value_id
                            AND fbus.bus_value_name = ''BUS_GP_DIR''

                            ) bus_dir

                 WHERE fbus.bus_value_id = fbusa.bus_value_id

                   AND bus_gp.bus_number2 IS NOT NULL
                   AND bus_gp.bus_group= fbus.bus_number1
                   AND fbus.bus_value = bus_dir.bus_number1
                   AND fbus.enabled_flag = ''Y''

                   AND fbus.bus_value_name  = :v_bus_name' || get_bus_number(iv_name) || ' 
                   AND fbus.bus_value = :v_bus_dir' || get_bus_dir(iv_bus)  ;


    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_abc 
      INTO v_return;

EXCEPTION

WHEN OTHERS THEN
  RETURN '';

 END;
```

Please help to verify the function issue with the code.

Comment: when I apply the function the error message to show on screen. Please help to give the comment. Thanks for all.

Comment: I have reverted your edit, please do not remove the content of your question once it has been resolved - it might help others. You can mark the answer as accepted if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

For the script, I would like design the new style and revise to get the parameter. The update script for change the design and give the sample. I don't want to show the original table name.

```
         SELECT 'BUS\' 
           || get_bus_dir(get_bus_number(bus.bus_value14))      
           || '\' 
           || bus.bus_value14 
           || '\' 
           || bus.bus_number1

    INTO v_bus_location

     FROM BUS_VL bus

        WHERE BUS_ID = N_ORG_ID          -- parameter
          AND BUS.BUS_dir_id = N_BUS_DIR_ID;      -- parameter
```